# How can I populate an array with selected values from multiple dynamic dropdownLists in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, formarray

I'm trying to populate a array of string with all selected values from my multiple dropdownlist dynamically generated from another array.
(exp: i have an locations: string[n]  and i want to build n dropdownlist each one contains all locations values, and i can select some values from my dropdownlist to build my array).

[image]

Here my HTML

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" gdColumns="repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr))" gdGap="10px"
                         class="zone-code-label" *ngFor="let _ of locations; index as index"
                         formArrayName="locationForm">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngFor="let _ of locationForm.controls; index as i">
                            <mat-label>{{'ASSET_CATALOG.FORM.FIELDS.LOCATION'| translate}}{{' '}}{{index + 1}}</mat-label>
                            <mat-select [formGroupName]="i"
                                        [placeholder]="'ASSET_CATALOG.FORM.FIELDS.LOCATION' | translate">
                                <mat-option>
                                    <ngx-mat-select-search formControlName="location"
                                                           [placeholderLabel]="'ASSET_CATALOG.FORM.CONFIG_LOCATION_SEARCH' | translate"
                                                           [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'ASSET_CATALOG.FORM.CONFIG_LOCATION_EMPTY' | translate"
                                    ></ngx-mat-select-search>
                                </mat-option>
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredLocationList| async"
                                            [value]="!!item? item.code: ''">
                                    <span> {{item.code + ' - ' + item.label}}</span>
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
```

And here my Forms declaration:

```
InitAssetCatalogForm(): void {
    this.assetCatalogForm.form = new FormGroup({
        code: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        label: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        price: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        measureUnit: new FormControl(null),
        supplier: new FormControl(''),
        ean: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        createdBy: new FormControl(null),
        createDate: new FormControl(null),
        nomenclature: new FormControl(null),
        duration: new FormControl(null),
        shelfLifeUnit: new FormControl(null),
        conditioning: new FormControl(null),
        weight: new FormControl(null),
        volume: new FormControl(null),
        minimumStock: new FormControl(null),
        height: new FormControl(null),
        length: new FormControl(null),
        width: new FormControl(null),
        ray: new FormControl(null),
        subRay: new FormControl(null),
        type: new FormControl(null),
        subType: new FormControl(null),
        segment: new FormControl(null),
        supplierCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        conditioningCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        measureUnitCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        nomenclatureRayCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        nomenclatureSubRayCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        nomenclatureTypeCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        nomenclatureSubTypeCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        nomenclatureSegmentCodeCtrl: new FormControl(null),
        locationForm: new FormArray([
            new FormGroup({
                location: new FormControl(null)
            })
        ])
    });
```

As you can see here my array is usually empty after submit and selected values are not taken.
[image: result]

The problem is with formcontrol and FormArray.

Any help please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (selectionChange) function to trigger an event, there you do whatever you want, including push to an array. This also should work for multiple tag.

First mat-select....

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="addItem($event.value)" multiple>
 <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value">
 {{item.value}}
  </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Second mat-select....

```
 <mat-select (selectionChange)="addItem($event.value)" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of something" [value]="s.value">
          {{s.value}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

Typescript

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.selectedItems=[];
}

 addItem(item:any){
   this.selectedItems.push(item);
 }
```

No need to mention you will also have to deal with unselected items, but that's up to you figure out how to remove it.